# How to open multiple windows on a button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popupwindow

In my design there are **three**  **buttons**. I want to **open new windows on each button click**. I have done upto open a  new window. But when I **click on the second button it opens in the same popup window**. How can I avoid this and open **three windows** when click on these **three buttons**?

> c# code

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ddlVal = ddlComp.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (ddlVal != "--Select The Competition--")
    {
        Session["ddlVal"] = ddlComp.SelectedValue.ToString();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "APPROVE_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'approved.aspx', null, 'resizable=yes, status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
    }
    else
    {
        WebMsgBox.Show("Select a competition");
    }
}
```

This is the code I have used for all the three buttons with different page names

Comment: Hi, can you clarify, this *code I have used for all the three buttons*  and there are 3 different pages but they all are called `'approved.aspx'`? Make each pages name different or use @Thangadurai's tip.

Comment: @ Jeremy I have used the same code to pop the window inside the button click event. approved.aspx is one of the pages and other two are named as reject and pending. Hope you got it

Comment: Maybe take the time to clarify next time... *when I click on the second button it opens in the same popup window* .... *this is the code I have used for all the three buttons* - not exactly clear when you dont highlight the different page names. But yeah I get it now.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I could find the answer. Thanks again for your effort Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the name parameter as '_blank' instead of null.
Change the below line in your code

```
window.open( 'approved.aspx', null,
```

to

```
window.open( 'approved.aspx', '_blank',
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to top-level browser windows, you cannot - browsers disable this for obvious reasons (pop-up blockers, etc). You also cannot have more than one JavaScript `alert()` window open at a time.

Your `WebMsgBox` class wraps the `alert()` function. So this not possible.

You will need to change your client-code to instead display multiple elements (e.g. absolutely-positioned `<div>` boxes with a modal rectangular appearance).